# Why don't combinators on iterators in stdlib propagate length hints?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a protocol for specifying a *length hint* ([`object.__length_hint__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__length_hint__)) on iterators. However, all the functions in the stdlib that I have tested with do not propagate this information. For example

```
>>> import operator
>>> operator.length_hint(range(10))
10
>>> operator.length_hint(enumerate(range(10)))
0
```

`enumerate`'s length hint could just return the length hint on the contained iterator. This lack of support makes length hints a lot less useful, because as soon as an iterator touches a combinator, any information on the length hint is lost. This is true of `map`, `zip`, and many functions in `itertools` as well

I don't see any correctness problems, because the length hint is just a hint anyway, and I don't see any performance problems, because this is just requires an additional instance method.

So why doesn't the stdlib take this opportunity?

Comment: Some discussion here: https://bugs.python.org/issue26828